# Chromosome length in Genetic Algorithms

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms

In order to find the appropriate length of chromosomes in GA programming, the author of [this book](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540606765) states:

> Suppose six decimal places for the variables' values is desirable.
>   It is clear that to achieve such precision each domain *`Di = [ai,bi]`* should be
>   cut into *`(bi - ai) * 10^6`* equal size ranges. Let us denote by *`mi`* the
>   smallest integer such that *`(bi - ai) * 10^6 <= 2^mi - 1`*. Then, a
>   representation having each variable *`xi`* coded as a binary string of
>   length *`mi`* clearly satisfies the precision requirement. Additionally, the following formula interprets each such string:
>
> `xi = ai + decimal(1001...001) * (bi - ai)/(2^mi - 1)`
>
> where `decimal(string)` represents the decimal value of that
>   binary string.

So here is my question: Why is the author using `(bi - ai)/(2^mi - 1)`? Why not `(bi - ai)/(2^mi)`? What is that `-1` for?

I searched it and I thought it might have something to do with the Mersenne Prime numbers because of the formulation!! I also checked out the [Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_(genetic_algorithms)#Length) as I thought it might be related to that, but these all seem completely unrelated!